# Powershell List Users who have RDS User Cal

Tags: windows-server-2012, powershell

I have a script to show users which haven't logged in recently which uses the Get -ADUser command with a filter on 'LastLoginTimeStamp'.

At the moment we disable accounts which haven't logged in for 90 days but I would like to take this a step further (as we are very limited on licenses) so that accounts without a license assigned are disabled after 30 days. If they already have a license assigned there isn't much point in disabling their account before that license expires.

As the Microsoft policy states 'any user with the ability to RDP must have a license' we are finding our self in the position where we have users that are not using RDP that we would like to disable and move to a group which doesn't permit RDP so we can free up a license for a new user.

I have came across multiple resources online which show how CSV reports can be produced but I can't find anything which shows how PowerShell can access this information. Is there a way or am I going to have to create a Powershell script to export a CSV license report and then another to compare the contents of that CSV to a list of users that haven't logged in within x days.

I am not looking for someone to write a script for me but to confirm if there is a way of doing this within Powershell.

Thanks,

Jack.

Comment: Serverfault is generally sensitive about script requests.  Update with a few resources you've checked or code you've already tried.  If you show what effort you've put in the community should respond positively.

Answer (score 1):

In most Remote Desktop/Terminal Server licensing situations I have worked with, this information is stored against the user object in Active Directory.  So getting this info out is a matter of knowing either the right LDAP filter or properties to query.

I've got a JScript-based report that I run to pull this information out, using `cscript.exe`, but the principals should be the same in Powershell.

In older servers/domains (<=2003), this information was stored in a single property, `terminalServer`; and in newer ones (>2003), this is spread across three properties (that I know of), called `msTSManagingLS`, `msTSLicenseVersion` and `msTSExpireDate`.  Obviously, with more information to go on, it is easier to pull this from newer domains (but, since you are working with Powershell, this is probably fine).

As such, assuming a version of Powershell and the AD module that supports scriptblock-style filters, the following (while slightly inefficient) should get you close:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {(msTSManagingLS -like '*' -and msTSLicenseVersion -like '*') -or (terminalServer -like '*')} -Properties * | fl -Property Name,sAMAccountName,msTS*
```

If you are running on an older Powershell version, you may need to craft the filter in a more LDAP-friendly fashion.  Maybe:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(|(&(msTSManagingLS=*)(msTSLicenseVersion=*))(terminalServer=*))' -Properties * | fl -Property Name,sAMAccountName,msTS*
```

Once you have the relevant AD objects in the pipeline, you can call regular Powershell on them (such as `Where-Object { $_.msTSExpireDate -lt [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-30) } | Disable-Account`)

Note that you'll want to do a *lot more work* than I have done above to make sure you don't disable any reasonable accounts (especially as it might render you and/or other admins unable to access your own machines to resolve).  At a minimum, I'd *certainly* look to limit this to users within a specific OU, e.g. by applying valid `-SearchBase` and `-SearchScope` parameters to your `Get-ADUser` call, or do more checking in your `Where-Object` filter (such as using `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` to make sure they're not in the *Domain Admins* group).

Also note that this only works for Remote Desktop servers running the full-blown Remote Desktop Services with a Remote Desktop Licensing Server.  You can't use this to check users who remote in using the two-connection Admin mode.

Answer (score 0):

As nobody know your environment (e.g. which terminal server you are really using as this information is missing, how its configured) its hard to provide a script which fits here. So what you might wish to build is an powerhsell script which used the output generated by the PerUserCALReport.vbs (see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh553161(v=ws.10).aspx) & [here](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/9739eaee-fb8a-4cb8-8456-7f138d175934/)). The export generated here is then directory re-imported via [Import-Csv](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176874.aspx). Use a foreach element here to check line by line and use Get-ADUser to get the last logon value. You can remove/add a user from a group or disable it here. That depends on you.

Please keep noted that there is a difference between LastLogon, LastLogonTimeStamp and LastLogonDate as written [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22461.understanding-the-ad-account-attributes-lastlogon-lastlogontimestamp-and-lastlogondate.aspx). So use the one which fits your environment, otherwise your script will not work correctly!